Create Inno Setup file to install a Schedule into Task Scheduler
I have made a very basic inno setup file that will simply add a task to task scheduler. When I try to run the task however in Windows 11 with no AV installed, the application is flagged as potentially containing a virus and is not run.
; -- Example1.iss --

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING .ISS SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=FileMaker AutoStart
AppVersion=1.5
WizardStyle=modern
DefaultDirName={autopf}\FMAutoStartInstaller
DefaultGroupName=FMAutoStartInstaller
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes

[Run] 
Filename: schtasks.exe; \
          Parameters:"/Create /TN ""FileMaker Auto Open"" /TR c:\autoOpen.bat /SC ONLOGON "][1]][1]

Ultimately I would also like to add this line to the inno setup file to copy a batch file to the c:
[Files]
Source: "autoOpen.bat"; DestDir: "c:\"

I have inno setup 6.2.2 installed

What is the name of your installer's executable? And are you signing it with a signing certificate? Also, are you aware that Windows doesn't like anything to be written directly to the root of the C:\ drive, even when a user has admin privileges?

There is no executable. I just want to add an entry to the Task Scheduler, and copy a batch file to the C:

If you're using Inno Setup, the setup script has to be compiled, which creates an executable (typically setup.exe). If you don't have an executable, your script will never execute - it's just a text file, and Windows doesn't flag text files as being malware. And if you don't need an actual installer (executable), why are you using Inno Setup at all, when you could do everything with just a batch file?

The reason why is that I want a neat installer to copy a batch file and create an "on login" task scheduler entry. Inno Setup does compile to creating an executable. Perhaps I am trying to put a square peg in a round hole. I can use just a batch file and I'll do that.
